# In ReactJS, how does index.js “activate” inside index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx, cpanel

I am having some trouble with a ReactJS app on Node.js. I cannot see anywhere wherein index.js would “activate” inside of index.html. Yes there is the div with id “root” in index.html and a snippet in index.js that reads “document.getElementById("root")”. Also the “main” key in package.json that should point towards the index.js file. However, I wonder is there something else that should trigger index.js to “activate” inside index.html, wherein index.js would render app.js.

I have searched for different places that may enact the index.js file inside my index.html but I cannot find anything. I get a blank page. I think I am getting a blank page because the index.js is not being read by the client browser. It is "disconnected" from index.html so to speak.

For reference I am making a ReactJS app on Node.js, I am using CPanel on an nginx server.
If anyone has any advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check the output after building.

Comment: The way this usually works is that your build process (via webpack or whatever) resolves all of your dependencies and outputs a bundled javascript file; it inserts a script tag referencing that file into a copy of your index.html, which is also included in the build output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if possible please provide code or picture. I have face some issue during troubleshooting. My suggestion for you is try insert breakpoint. It can be in your ts, js or html and debug it.

`VS Code`

[image]
[image]

`Browser (F12 -> Debugger -> Ctrl + Shift + F -> find the file)`
[image]
[image]

Track if the program ran that file or the function you wanted and should able to solve the problem by yourself